# Using FileRandomAccessStream in metro app

Tags: sql, database, wcf, microsoft-metro

```
private ImageSource _image = null;
    private String _imagePath = null;

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._image == null && this._imagePath != null)
            {
                //this._image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(VMDataCommon._baseUri, this._imagePath));

                this.LoadImages();
            }
            return this._image;
        }

        set
        {
            this._imagePath = null;
            this.SetProperty(ref this._image, value);
        }
    }

    private async void LoadImages()
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile imageFile = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(_imagePath);

        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();

        FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

        img.SetSource(stream);

        //img = await LoadImage(imageFile);
        this._image = img;
        //return this._image;
    }
```

This is the method I use to retrieve the image in the pictures folder. But I am not sure why when I run the app sometimes it doesn't display and sometimes it display. Thanks.

Comment: Ur testing in simulator ?

Comment: When I run it randomly display the picture

Comment: Its a dot net framework problem .. Wait Ill share the link. Have tested in a windows surface tablet ?

Comment: Wait ill get back to you with the link  mean while you can search *bitmap rendering issue in metro app*.

Comment: How is it ? Did you find the link ?

Comment: What is the dot net framework in your machine. Go for dot net 4.5 I guess it will solve the issue. And m still banging my head on it :)

Comment: It is disable how do I set ?

Comment: Check steps and link . Download and install from here. Then try and let me know. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx

Comment: I did what you told me to installed but it still the same

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/252d4d14-1db3-4f04-93b6-d2eab2c386bc/c-metro-displaying-images-in-a-listview-or-gridviewI got see someone in msdn with same problem: